# Не работает калькулятор proteus+bascom

Tags: proteus

Пробовал сделать калькулятор из темы но не получилось, помогите решить проблему: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24558232/keypad-dont-work-correctly-in-bascom-avr-program-and-proteus

Код взял из статьи и засунул в BASCOM-AVR, выбрал чип m32def.dat, компилировал и открыл в микроконтроллере .hex, частоту поменял на 2MHz, запускаю симуляцию, нажимаю на кнопки и ничего не происходит.

[image: Схема с протеуса]